# align two overlapping linear layouts like two rows

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm having two Linear Layouts inside a Relative Layout.

The two Linear Layouts are overlapping each other no matter what I do.

I want to arrange them in a row order (one below the other) not overlapping.

I was thinking of using Table Layout if Linear Layout is having so much problems but thought to ask here if at all there maybe some benefits with Linear Layouts.

[image: layout image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <!--This layout only holds a TextView
            inside a CardView-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="this is another test this is another test"
        android:textColor="#0C0909"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/nvoids_logo_foreground"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why not use a constratintlayout?

Comment: @Raghunandan which one? replace RelativeLayout or LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: yes use one constraintlayout

Answer (score 0):

Use height wrap_content instead of match_parent in your Linearlayouts. And add android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout" in your 2nd Linerarlayout.

Change it like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--This layout only holds a TextView
                inside a CardView-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="this is another test this is another test"
            android:textColor="#0C0909"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/nvoids_logo_foreground"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid deep view hierarchy ,use constraintLayout to get better performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="this is another test this is another test"
        android:textColor="#0C0909"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:layout_margin="32dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: and I thought google was helping but just instead of align statements and to make designing a hell they have come up with layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf , layout_constraintStart_toStartOf, layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf etc. etc. and what not. Crazy stuff...